# How to handle keyboard events in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3, keyboard-events

I would like to activate/deactivate an `ol.interaction` based on the fact a key is pressed/released on the map.
I already did something like

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',... myIneteraction.setActive(true) ...)
```

...but was wondering if there is a cleaner approach (eg. listening on some native `ol.[...]` event). I don't understand when (if ever, apparently never) keyboard events are fired by the `ol.Map`.

Comment: Why your solution is not clean enough?